# PostgreSQL permissions

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I'm trying to achieve a simple architecture:

1. An organization has many users
2. A user belongs to many organizations
3. A user can connect
4. A user can join and leave an organization
5. A user can read-only tables granted to organizations

First, securing permissions, as recommended in many places (https://ankane.org/postgres-users, https://marcyes.com/2016/0922-messing-with-postgresql-users-and-permissions/)

```sql
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE stamped_development FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

Then, creating an *organizations* role with read permissions:

```sql
CREATE ROLE organizations;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO organizations;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES in SCHEMA public TO organizations;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE organizations IN SCHEMA public
  GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO organizations;
```

Then, creating a *users* role with connect permissions:

```sql
CREATE ROLE users WITH LOGIN;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE stamped_development TO users;
```

Create an organization and a user:

```sql
CREATE ROLE org_123 IN ROLE organizations;
CREATE ROLE user_123 WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'secret' IN ROLE users;
```

Joining and leaving organizations as a user:

```sql
GRANT org_123 TO user_123;
REVOKE org_123 FROM user_123;
```

```
\du+
                                               List of roles
   Role name   |                         Attributes                         |    Member of    | Description
---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------
 org_123       | Cannot login                                               | {organizations} |
 organizations | Cannot login                                               | {}              |
 user_123      | Cannot login                                               | {users,org_123} |
 users         |                                                            | {}              |
```

Problems:

- `user_123` doesn't seem to inherit `LOGIN` from `users`
- Even when granting `LOGIN` to `user_123` it seems like `user_123` can't `SELECT` tables in the public schema

Any thoughts on what's missing?

*Edited to reflect fixes suggested in the answers*

Comment: 'it seems like `user_123` can't `SELECT` tables in the public schema' - does this manifest in some kind of error?  Does it apply to all tables in `public`, or only to the ones created after `GRANT SELECT ...`?